# When is our next election going to be held?

Tags: discussion

From the past posts on Biology meta one can make out that our first election took place last year around the month of Jun. It is going to be 1st Sept 2016 tomorrow.I'm curious to know how often does election take place on Stack Exchange rather when are we going to have our next election?

I'm really interested in the activities of this community. $:)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For questions about general things on stackexchange, it is always a good idea to search on [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) for an answer. When searching meta for "election" you will find this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99512/when-do-moderator-elections-take-place).

Part of the answer says:

> Although we'll reach out to moderators on the anniversary of their
>   last election, just to see how they're doing, elections do not always
>   take place at the same time every year. Sometimes a year can even go
>   by without any election at all. Most elections are scheduled as a
>   result of moderators reaching out to Stack Exchange to ask for
>   additional help.